# Do not want to clean up the data of the independent chain, how to seamlessly connect to the parachain?

Tags: parachain

And, can I continue to run independently after my `parachain` goes offline and I leave the `relaychain`?

Comment: Please change your question to have one question only, and provide more context, instead of two semi-related questions.

Answer (score 4):

Going from a solo chain to a parachain accepts different approaches, but you will have to check that the different types you are using on your chain will be compatible with /understood by (call it whatever you please) by the ecosystem that you are about to connect to. This translates to you might have to migrate some part of your state.
As an example I know this tool https://github.com/centrifuge/centrifuge-cli/tree/main/packages/plugins/migration that was used by Centrifuge team to do this migration. So a similar scenario.

On your follow up question, my two cents are, if you are connecting as a parachain you are getting finality from the relay chain, then why running on solo again where finality is granted by your own chain. The flow for a parachain that off boards from its slot is to become a parathread from which state is possible to on board again as a parachain, though different ways of tackling this have been seen already in the ecosystem, for instance getting a another slot when the first lease is close to finish.

I still would like to know more of your motivations from going back to solo after being a parachain. Take into account that what this means is that your chain must have some mechanism to know where to provide finality and when not to. And if that is managed, building the system in a way that going throw all the state is still verifiable.

Don't get me wrong here, I would say this is possible, but fairly complex to maintain over time. And for sure there is a bunch of details that I am missing in what I have written in this message, but seeing such a capable system going live would be amazing.

Answer (score 0):

@alejandro-martínez

Is there any such system built where it is possible to switch between solochain and parachain whenever we want?