# Would it be possible to run solochain and parachain from single code base?

Tags: polkadot

A few months ago, we worked on a parachain and have been trying to integrate into Kusama but we couldn't win the slot.

This is affecting our business. Would it be possible to have a single code base for both solochain and parachain so that we can switch to either parachain or solochain according to the requirement?

Or if we build a separate solochain, would it be easy to migrate storage into parachain, if we get slot in future for our parachain?

Comment: Check out this answer I posted in another question. https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/2334/165

Answer (score 1):

Definitely. If you look at cumulus repo that's got several runtimes that are sharing pallets and some common configuration. There's also the parachain-template that is a different node (different binary) and yet still shares some crates with the the polkadot-parachain node.