# Can a private network migrate to parachain?

Tags: parachain, relay-chain

Is it possible to migrate a running solo chain to a parachain in order to gain decentralized proofs of validity? I don't know if there's any material related to this topic available (I haven't found any), but I was wondering if it is possible to do so.

The idea is to develop a private network where only certain people will have access, but later on, I would like the chain to be integrated as a parachain, or at least get access to decentralized validation for blocks.

UPDATE: Can we develop a solo chain and a parachain using the same runtime and node? Using the parachain-template I'm not able to produce blocks the same way I could with the node-template using the --dev flag (I guess it is because there's no GRANDPA pallet included)

Answer (score 1):

I believe [this guide](https://docs.substrate.io/reference/how-to-guides/parachains/convert-a-solo-chain/) describes how to do this.

EDIT: There are some related answers here:

- https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/2911/2673
- https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/2334/2673

Comment: It's not really what I'm looking for, let me quote some of the content `This is an overview, not a proper how-to guide presently!`

Comment: @andresvsm Oh, sorry than. :( But at least you know it's possible. :)

Comment: @andresvsm I think you should check out these answers:
https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/2911/2673
https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/2334/2673

Comment: that answer was definitely helpful, now I have a better vision on what It's possible and what not at the moment, thx!