# Add hyperledger Fabric as a parachain to relaychain in polkadot

Tags: polkadot, relay-chain

Is it possible to connect hyperledger fabric to relaychain as one of the parachain...

Answer (score 0):

Is not an easy answer because I am not familiar with the codebase of Hyperledger Fabric but it will have to be Polkadot compatible in order to be a Polkadot Parachain.

One example is that the Polkadot Host requires that the state transitions performed on parachains be specified as a **[Wasm executable](https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/learn-wasm)**.

You can take a look to all technicals details of a Parachain in this guide:

[The Polkadot Parachain Host Implementers' Guide](https://paritytech.github.io/polkadot/book/)

The easy way to build a Parachain is first to build your chain using [**Substrate**](https://substrate.io/): a blockchain framework that provides the basic building blocks of a blockchain (things like the networking layer, consensus, a Wasm interpreter) while providing an intuitive way to construct your runtime.

And the use [**Cumulus**](https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus). Cumulus is an extension to Substrate that makes it easy to make any Substrate-built runtime into a Polkadot-compatible parachain.

Cumulus handles the network compatibility overhead that any parachain would need to implement to be connected to Polkadot. This includes:

- Cross-chain message passing (XCMP)
- Out-of-the-box Collator node setup
- An embedded full client of the Relay Chain
- Block authorship compatibility

This is a guide about how to add Cumulus to a solo chain: https://docs.substrate.io/reference/how-to-guides/parachains/convert-a-solo-chain/.

There is already a [Substrate Parachain Templat](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-parachain-template)e node that has added Cumulus into a Substrate chain already.

Check this answer from StackExchange too: https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/2334/2762

There is also another alternative to make two economically sovereign and technologically diverse chains to communicate with each other: **[Bridges](https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/learn-bridges)**.
There is some projects to connect other networks to Polkadot for example [Bitcoin](https://docs.polkabtc.io/#/) or [Ethereum](https://github.com/ChainSafe/ChainBridge) there is another alternative, [Bridges](https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/learn-bridges).