# how we can migrate the solochain data to the parachain?

Tags: parachain, solo-chain

If we currently have the live solochain and in future we need to go on parachain how we will migrate the data from the existing solochain to parachain.

Answer (score 2):

There is a newly released video by parity on [launching a Parachain](https://youtu.be/7DZwVXzi9x0). It might help you.

Comment: Thanks @Just, let me know if there is any questions/feedback you need

Answer (score 2):

Check the answer to this previous question on StackExchange: [Do not want to clean up the data of the independent chain, how to seamlessly connect to the parachain?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/2334/2762).

I like to share too this video of the Sub0 conference: [Sub0 Online: Storage Migration - Standalone chain to Parachain](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sIgvyRFs-N4)

Also is not about migrate data but worth to check this tutorial in Substrate docs about how to [Convert a solo chain into a parachain](https://docs.substrate.io/reference/how-to-guides/parachains/convert-a-solo-chain/).